# Is Elastic Search Engine good for non-full text search scenario

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, full-text-search

We are building an e-commerce application. We have a table having millions of records in mysql db and columns are like product-id,product-name, cost. Here we are providing search filter to search product by name, cost etc.The search filter will be mostly consists of "=",">","<" operators. Since these columns are not long strings and inverted indexing of elastic search engine may not be that useful compared to indexing in mysql db. So is it wise to use elastic search engine for this scenario? Will elastic search engine will provide better performance then RDBMS in such cases where we don't have to do full text search?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find your answer here: https://lucidworks.com/post/full-text-search-engines-vs-dbms/.

But in short I would not expect it to provide an advantage in performance for your case. You might find usage in the options coming along with using the elastic stack like creating dashboards of the data, alerting, ...

Anyhow I would suggest doing some tests, it's rather easy to make a basic setup on elk in my opinion. This way you will now for sure, maybe keep us posted on your findings?

Comment: So it means elastic search engine should be used only for full-text search?

Comment: No it has other strengths too, but more specific for your case I found this:
Elasticsearch is designed as a search engine, which makes it very good at getting back the top documents that match a query. However, it is not as good for workloads that fall into the database domain, such as retrieving all documents that match a particular query.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/general-recommendations.html

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch would do a great job for this scenario, in case you are interested in filtering content and getting X number of result. Elasticsearch is very good at filtering content, and returning exactly what you look for - at high speed